# Expectation maximization when support of likelihood is parameterized

Tags: self-study, estimation, inference, expectation-maximization, conditional-expectation

I'm trying to solve a homework problem and  I'm not getting the answer I expect.

The problem is from Pattern Classification by Duda,Hart,Stork (problem 3.47)

> Consider $\mathcal{D} = \left\{\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}3\\3\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}2\\*\end{pmatrix} \right\}$, sampled from a two-dimensional (separable) distribution $p(x_1,x_2)=p_{1}(x_1)p_{2}(x_2)$, with
>   \begin{equation}
>     p_{1}(x) \sim \begin{cases} \frac{1}{\theta_1}e^{-x/\theta_1}  & \text{if}~x  \geq 0\\0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}.
> \end{equation}
>   and
>   \begin{equation}
>     p_{2}(x) \sim \begin{cases} \frac{1}{\theta_2} & \text{if}~0 \leq x \leq \theta_2 \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}
> \end{equation}
>   As usual, $*$ represents a missing feature value.
>
> **(a)** Start with an initial estimate of $\theta^0=\begin{pmatrix}2\\4\end{pmatrix}$ and analytically calculate $Q(\theta; \theta^0)$ - The **E step** of the EM algorithm. Be sure to consider the normalization of your distribution.
>
> **(b)** Find the $\theta$ that maximizes your $Q(\theta; \theta^0)$ - The **M step**.

$Q$ is defined as

\begin{equation}
Q(\theta; \theta^i) = \mathbb{E}_{\mathcal{D}_b}\left[ \ln p(\mathcal{D}_g, \mathcal{D}_b ; \theta) | \mathcal{D}_g ; \theta^i \right]
\end{equation}

where $\mathcal{D}_g$ is the "good" (observed) data and $\mathcal{D}_b$ is the "bad" (missing) data. Note that $\mathcal{D}=\mathcal{D}_g \cup \mathcal{D}_b$.

I'm assuming i.i.d. sampling and we are given that the features are independent. 
For this reason I would expect that EM converges to the maximum likelihood estimates which is $\theta=(2,3)^T$. So I expect my solution for part **(b)**, $\theta^1$, to be closer to $(2,3)^T$ than $\theta^0$. However this doesn't seem to be the case.

---

### Attempt

In this problem $\mathcal{D}_g$ contains 5 observations and $\mathcal{D}_b = \{ x_{32} \}$ is the missing data. I assume the domain of $Q$ is $\theta \in \mathbb{R}^2_{++}$. Also let $\theta = (\theta_1, \theta_2)^T$ and $\theta^0 = (\theta_0^1, \theta_0^2)^T$.

\begin{align}
Q(\theta; \theta^i) &= \mathbb{E}_{\mathcal{D}_b}\left[ \ln p(\mathcal{D}_g, \mathcal{D}_b ; \theta) | \mathcal{D}_g ; \theta^0 \right] \\
&= \mathbb{E}_{x_{32}}\left[ \ln p(1,1;\theta) + \ln p(3,3;\theta) + \ln p_{1}(2;\theta_1) + \ln p_{2}(x_{32};\theta_2) | \mathcal{D}_g ; \theta^0 \right] \\
&= \ln p(1,1;\theta) + \ln p(3,3;\theta) + \ln p_{1}(2;\theta_1) + \mathbb{E}_{x_{32}} \left[ \ln p_{2}(x_{32};\theta_2) | \mathcal{D}_g ; \theta^0 \right] \\
\end{align}

Consider the expression in two parts $Q(\theta; \theta^0) = f(\theta) + g(\theta; \theta^0)$

where

\begin{align} 
f(\theta) &= \ln p(1,1;\theta) + \ln p(3,3;\theta) + \ln p_{1}(2;\theta_1) \\
&= \begin{cases} -3 \ln \theta_1 - \frac{6}{\theta_1} - 2 \ln \theta_2 & \text{if}~\theta_2 \geq 3 \\ -\infty & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}.
\end{align}

assuming $\ln(0) = -\infty$, and

\begin{align}
g(\theta; \theta^0) &= \mathbb{E}_{x_{32}} \left[ \ln p_{2}(x_{32};\theta_2) | \mathcal{D}_g ; \theta^0 \right] \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} {\left( \ln p_{2}(x_{32};\theta_2)\right) p_{2}(x_{32} | \mathcal{D}_g ; \theta^0)  dx_{32}}
\end{align}

Note that $x_{32}$ is independent of $\mathcal{D}_g$ because i.i.d. and $p(x_1,x_2)=p_1(x_1)p_2(x_2)$. Therefore $p_{2}(x_{32} | \mathcal{D}_g ; \theta^0) = p_{2}(x_{32} ; \theta^0_2) = 1/4$ if $x_{32} \in [0,4]$, and $0$ otherwise so then

\begin{align}
g(\theta; \theta^0) &= \frac{1}{4} \int_{0}^{4} \ln p_{2}(x_{32} ; \theta_2) dx_{32} \hspace{50pt} \text{(almost surely)} \\
&= \begin{cases} -\ln \theta_2 & \text{if}~\theta_2 \geq 4 \\ -\infty & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}
\end{align}

Therefore
\begin{equation}
Q(\theta ; \theta^0) = \begin{cases}
    -3\ln\theta_1 - \frac{6}{\theta_1} - 3\ln\theta_2 & \text{if}~\theta_2 \geq 4 \\
-\infty & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

Clearly $\theta^1 = \text{arg}\max_{\theta} Q(\theta ; \theta^0) = (2,4)^T$.

---

Again this solution disagrees with my belief that $\theta^1$ should be closer to $(2,3)$ than $\theta^0$. Is this belief wrong? Have I made a mistake somewhere?
 I really appreciate if someone could help me understand. I think there may be a mistake in the calculation of $g(\theta ; \theta^0)$ but I can't see it.

Comment: Can you please explain why it has to be $\theta_2 \geq 3$ in the calculation of $f(\theta)$?

Comment: @fear Sure, it comes from the definition of $p_2$. We know that $p(3,3 ; \theta) = p_1(3; \theta_1) p_2(3; \theta_2)$. If $\theta_2 < 3$ then $p_2(3; \theta_2) = 0$, if $\theta_2 \geq 3$ then $p_2(3; \theta_2) = 1/\theta_2$.

Comment: Thank you! One more question. Duda, in the problem solutions says that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} p(x_1)dx_1=1$ and thus $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\theta_1}e^{-\frac{x_1}{\theta_1}} dx_1 =1$ and thus $\theta_1=1$. This is different from your expectation (2, 3) and also $\theta_1$ will not change values. I don't understand why $p(x_1)=\frac{1}{\theta_1}e^{-\frac{x_1}{\theta_1}}$. To my understanding it should be $p(x_1)=p_1(x_1)p_2(x_1)=\frac{1}{\theta_1}e^{-\frac{x_1}{\theta_1}} \frac{1}{\theta_2}$ and then integrate from 0 to infinity. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: @fear $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\theta_1}e^{-\frac{x_1}{\theta_1}}dx_1 = 1$ is false. Remember that $p_1(x) = 0$ for $x < 0$ which means $1 = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{p_1(x_1)dx_1} = \int_{0}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{\theta_1}e^{-\frac{x_1}{\theta_1}}dx_1}$ for all $\theta_1 > 0$.

Comment: @fear I don't understand your second question since $p_1(x) = \frac{1}{\theta_1} e^{-\frac{x}{\theta_1}}$ by definition. Did I write something that contradicts this somewhere? Your confusion may be from the fact that the textbook uses $p$ for both marginal and joint densities. I changed that in this question to avoid ambiguity. Generally you infer the proper density function by the subscript of the independent variable, in this case the use of $x_1$ indicates that $p$ refers to the first marginal distribution ($p_1$ in my question).

Comment: My question is about M-step. If we get Duda's solution then $\theta_1=1$. Using this I can get $\theta_2=3$ from your calculations. But if this assumptions is wrong, how do you calculate the M-step?

Comment: @fear I derived a closed expression for $Q(\theta ; \theta^0)$ which is $-\infty$ for all $\theta_2 < 4$. Obviously then $\theta_2 = 3 \Rightarrow Q = -\infty$ which doesn't maximize $Q$. To maximize for $\theta_1$ just solve $\frac{\partial Q}{\partial \theta_1} = 0$ assuming that $\theta_2 \geq 4$. To maximize over $\theta_2$ note that $-3 \ln \theta_1 - \frac{6}{\theta_1} -3 \ln{\theta_2}$ is monotonically decreasing for positive $\theta_2$ so it must be $\theta_2 = 4$.

Comment: @fear Also, it might be worth mentioning that the Stork's solution is probably wrong. It appears he fell into the trap discussed in the accepted answer to this question. Take away from the answer is that EM doesn't always work as expected when the [support](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_(mathematics)) of the distribution is a function of the parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think $g(\theta;\theta^0)$ may have a mistake. If $0 < \theta_2 < 4$, then $$g(\theta;\theta^0)=\frac{1}{4} \int_0^{\theta_2} \ln \frac{1}{\theta_2} dx_{32} = -\frac{\theta_2}{4} \ln \theta_2.$$ Thus, $Q(\theta;\theta^0) = -3 \ln \theta_1-\frac{6}{\theta_1} -(2+\frac{\theta_2}{4}) \ln \theta_2$ if $3 \le \theta_2 < 4$.

**EDIT**

From [paper "Exercises in EM"](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00031305.2000.10474546):

"E-step does not simply involve replacing missing data by
their conditional expectation (although this is true for many
important applications of the algorithm). Rather, the E-step
takes the expected value of the complete-data log-likelihood
function, conditional on the observed data. If the likelihood
function takes value zero in a subset of the parameter space,
then the log-likelihood function does not exist, and the EM
algorithm is not applicable."

I am just replacing the missing data by the conditional expectation above and this is not correct. I think we need to be very careful with non-exponential family distributions. In the [book](http://mayagupta.org/publications/EMbookGuptaChen2010.pdf), it mentions that "If the support does depend on $\theta$, then the monotonicity of the EM algorithm might not hold."

Comment: I can see that this gives me the expected solution. Can you explain why this is justified as opposed to assigning $-\infty$?

Comment: I do not see it is $-\infty$ . $g(\theta;\theta^0)=\frac{1}{4} \int_0^{4} \ln p_{2}(x_{32};\theta_2) dx_{32}$ is correct, but when $0 < \theta_2 <4$, $p_{2}(x_{32};\theta_2)$ is nonzero when $x_{32} \in (0,\theta_2)$. Thus, the integral is from 0 to $\theta_2$.

Comment: Maybe I'm thinking of it wrong. I'm considering $x_{32}$ as a r.v. with distribution $U(0,4)$ and $\ln p(x_{32} ; \theta_2)$ as a function of that random variable. Since $\ln p(x_{32} ; \theta_2) = -\infty$ for $x_{32} > \theta_2$ then if $\theta_2 < 4$ the function $\ln p(x_{32} ; \theta_2)$ takes on the value $-\infty$ with non-zero probability. Hense the expected value is $-\infty$ no?

Comment: Do we simply take the expected value over $\textbf{support} p(x ; \theta_2) \cap \textbf{support} p(x ; \theta_2^0)$ ?

Comment: I think you are right, sorry about my mistake. The algorithm simply got stuck at the initial values.After reading several materials, I realized that I fell into a trap. Please see my edits and thanks for asking this problem.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer this. So it looks like in general from reading your references we can't assume a MLE solution in all cases and this happens to be one of those cases. In general we also can't be guarenteed convergence (or more specifically the conditional expectation doesn't exist) if the support of the likelihood is a function of $\theta$.

Comment: Yes. It might not converge to local maximum even for exponential families if the starting point is not good.